# How can I evaluate multiple hypotheses simultanousely using the bootstrap?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, multiple-comparisons, bootstrap

Suppose you have two null hypothesis for two parameters, $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ based on the same variable $X$. So for example, $\theta_1$ is mean of $X$ in group 1, whereas $\theta_2$ is mean of $X$ in group 2.

In reality there may be four true states

1. $\theta_1 \ne 0$ and $\theta_2 \ne 0$
2. $\theta_1 = 0$ and $\theta_2 \ne 0$
3. $\theta_1 \ne 0$ and $\theta_2 = 0$
4. $\theta_1 = 0$ and $\theta_2 = 0$

My practical goal is to test with some alpha level in which of the four situations I am in.

I could asses $$H_0:\theta_1 = \theta_2 = 0.$$ for example using ANOVA and then, if rejected, I can use multiple testing to evaluate group differences.

However, when we bootstrap statistics instead, it is easy to get a p-value of $H_0:\theta_1 = 0$. But I do not know how to test multiple hypotheses somultanously.

**My questions is**: how can I use the bootstrap to determine with some allowed error (or with a probability, as in Bayesian statistics) in which of the four situations I am in? You could solve this problem for group means, as in the example, or more generally, in saying, how I should use the bootstrap in simultanous tests of multiple hypotheses (e.g. if $\theta$ is not a simple statistic, such as group mean).